# How to model a playlist in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, playlist

I’m creating a website for a record company I’m starting.

Right now I have a working artist (user) model with validation. I now need to create a way for artists create a playlist with their songs. I also need this music to be downloadable for everyone.

This is my thinking:

Create an Album model and a Song model.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

An artist will create an Album using an Album form. Then on a separate form they will create a Song that will belong to a certain Album. They will add each Song to an Album separately, so if they have 10 Songs in one Album they will fill out the Song form 10 times.

On the Artist show page, I can call the Artist’s Album to display a list of Songs belonging to that Album. Those songs will then be playable via a player of some sort. Then when an non-logged-in-user clicks on a download button, they are brought to a download page where they can download a .zip file of the Album with the Songs nicely packaged up.

I want this to be very similar to the way Bandcamp does it.

How can I go about doing this? or at least get started?

Comment: just one step at a time.  You've got a good starting point and a good logical path.  No doubt you'll hit road blocks but you need to do steps 1-10 before we can help you with step 28.

Comment: Rich clearly has a well thought out and good answer but I wanted to offer one modeling suggestion: if you think that at any point down the road, a Song could belong to more than 1 album, you may want to consider using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship on the song model (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). Using a belongs_to, and there is nothing wrong with that, means that if a song ends up on a 'greatest hits' album and on its original album, you end up with duped data. Might not be an issue for you but thought I'd note it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to do something like this:

--

**Admin**

Firstly, you'll need an *admin area*

This will be where your "artist" can upload their songs / albums, allowing you to create an authenticated area for that person. To do this is actually quite simple:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root: "albums#index"
   resources :albums, except: :show
end
resources :albums, only: [:index, :show]

#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
class Admin::AlbumsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
      @albums = Album.all
   end

   def new
      @album = Album.new
      @album.songs.build
   end

   def create
      @album = Album.new album_params
      @album.save
   end

   private

   def album_params
     params.require(:album).permit(:your_album_params, songs_attributes: [:songs, :attributes])
   end
end
```

This should be backed up with the appropriate models:

```
#app/models/artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  # devise code here
end

#app/models/album.rb
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :artist

   has_many :songs
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs
end

#app/models/song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end
```

You'll have to authenticate with the likes of [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) by applying it to your `artist` model. Although I won't go into details about that, you'll be best using [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise):

[image]

A very good resource on creating [an amazing admin area in Rails can be found here](http://www.iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1)

--

**Nested Attributes**

You may notice the use of [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in the models above.

This method gives you the ability to pass associative form data through models, thus allowing you to capture "child" data on your parent form itself.

Without going into too much detail (specifically about how to add new "associated" values on the fly), here's how you should render the "songs" part of your album form (if you're creating the song):

```
#app/views/admin/albums/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :songs do |s| %>
      <%= s.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Recommendation**

The front-end "user downloads" part of the app would be the simplest to implement.

You'll basically need to make a controller to manage the downloads, and then ensure you have the flow set up to get it working correctly:

```
#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb -> notice no "admin" folder?
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @albums = Album.all
   end

   def show
      @album = Album.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

As mentioned, however, you're *probably* going to be best suited thinking about things in terms of a [*flow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming) -- IE how your user / data will move through the application. This should give you a step-by-step process of approaching the issue you face, thus providing you with more robust questions / answers